# Swift generic superclass' init not accessible when constructing its subclass

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following codes:

```
class ILProperty<T> {
    var value: T?
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

typealias ILStringProperty = ilStringProperty<String>
class ilStringProperty<String>: ILProperty<String> {
}

let x = ILStringProperty("X")
```

The last line is a compile error:

> 'ILStringProperty' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

If I override the init:

```
override init(_ value: String) {
    super.init(value)
}
```

will work but I don't like it. Why do I need to override it when I won't add/modify it?

Am I doing something wrong?

**Update**: Follow up questions to answers from Nikita Leonov and Icaro

First regarding all properties must have default value, I do think I satisfied this rule where an optional var is defaulted with a nil value, isn't it? Though even if I write `var value: T? = nil` doesn't solve it.

Then from the same [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222) section "Automatic Initializer Inheritance":

> superclass initializers are automatically inherited if certain conditions are met

One condition is:

> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.

Where I do think the code above does met. This actually will work if I will not use generics:

```
class ILProperty {
    var value: Any?
    init(_ value: Any) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
class ILStringProperty: ILProperty {
}
let x = ILStringProperty("X")
```

Should this rule also apply to generic classes?

Answer (score 1):

The last line in your code sample no longer gives a compile error, (since Swift 3). There is no mention of this in the [Swift 3 Language Changes](https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-0-released/), so I can only assume that this was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

From [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html):

> Swift provides a default initializer for any structure or base class
>   that provides default values for all of its properties and does not
>   provide at least one initializer itself. The default initializer
>   simply creates a new instance with all of its properties set to their
>   default values.

Your class ilStringProperty is not a base class as it inherit from ILProperty so it must have an initializer, if you create one or override one does not matter since you have at least one initializer in your class as swift will not give one for free.

Comment: Hm. You are right. With this rules in mind it should inherit. It works for non generic class, but fails on generic class — http://swiftstub.com/239455006/

Really interesting case. I also found similar question on Apple dev forums, but it is not answered yet — https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5389

Comment: Thanks for the similar question link

Answer (score 0):

As [ganzogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577432/ganzogo) mentioned it seems to be working fine with the latest Swift (3.0). Also, why do you declare a separate class to assign to the `typealias`? I've tried this in a Playground and it seems ok:

```
class ILProperty<T> {
    var value: T?
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

typealias ILStringProperty = ILProperty<String>
let x = ILStringProperty("X")
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another quote from Apple documentation

> Unlike subclasses in Objective-C, Swift subclasses do not inherit
>   their superclass initializers by default. Swift’s approach prevents a
>   situation in which a simple initializer from a superclass is inherited
>   by a more specialized subclass and is used to create a new instance of
>   the subclass that is not fully or correctly initialized.

In the [Swift Programming Language document from apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) look section "Initializer Inheritance and Overriding".

I do n understand your frustration but Swift's way of dealing with initializer is conceptually better.

Comment: There is also a note following the phase you pasted.