# Inheriting initializer from generic class

Tags: ios, swift, generics, inheritance, swift2

I've seen some discussions about this problem, but have not read a satisfactory explanation. Can anybody tell me why this does not work?

```
class Parent<T> {

  var data:T

  init(data:T) {
    self.data = data
  }
}

class Child : Parent<Int> {}

let c = Child(data: 4)
```

The last line gives the error:

`'Child' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`

Do I really need to implement the initializer just to call `super`?

**Edit:**

To give a bit of context, the real code looks closer to the below. I have an `Action` class which uses generics, because I have another bit of code which can chain actions together and I want to use Swift's type safety to ensure that actions can be chained. Then I have a bunch of subclasses classes (e.g. `CustomAction`). I am looking for a way to avoid overriding the `init` method in each of the subclasses. Or alternatively, I want to understand why that's not possible.

```
class Action<Input, Output> {

  var cachedOutput:Output?

  init(cachedOutput:Output?) {
    self.cachedOutput = cachedOutput
  }
}

protocol CustomInput {}
protocol CustomOutput {}

class CustomAction : Action<CustomInput, CustomOutput> {
}
```

Comment: Similar question (but without accepted answer) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040044/swift-generic-superclass-init-not-accesible-when-constructing-its-subclass.

Comment: Since you are subclassing `Parent` presumably there is some difference in behaviour between the class with an Int and the generic case. It doesn't seem unreasonable that you are required to explicity implement an initialiser.

Comment: Absolutely there is some difference in behaviour - just not in the behaviour of the initializer. It is worth noting that if I had any other method defined in `Parent` (e.g. `func setData(data:T) { self.data = data }`), then I wouldn't need to override this in `Child` - it would just work. Why is the initializer any different?

Comment: in your 'real' code, even though you will override initializer, the type of Output will be undeclared. and what about Input? finally, you will need at least an initializer for CustomOutput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now works in Swift 3. My original example now compiles. There is no mention of this in the [Swift 3 Language changes](https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-0-released/), so I can only assume that this was a bug.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you really need to override init method ..

```
class Parent<T> {

    var data:T

    init(data:T) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

class Child<T> : Parent<T> {
    override init(data: T) {
        super.init(data: data)
    }
}

let c = Child(data: 4)       // Child<Int>
let c2 = Child(data: "alfa") // Child<String>
```

what are the errors ...

```
// what is the type T ? it is undeclared!
class Child2: Parent2<T> {}
// how to specialize non-generic type Parent ? how to create it?
// i need an initializer in class Child3 ... Hm ...
class Child3: Parent<Int> {}

// cannot specialize non-generic type 'Parent'
class Child3: Parent<Int> {
    override init(data: Int) {
        super.init(data: data)
    }
}
// So, Child3 must be of the same specialized type as Parent!!
```

that is terrible, isn't it? so look at my final example !

```
class Parent<T> {

    var data:T

    init(data:T) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

class Child<Double> : Parent<String> {
    init(data: Double) {
        super.init(data: "\(data)")
    }
}

let c = Child(data: 4)       // Child<Int> !!!!!
let d = Child(data: true)    // Child<Bool> !!!
```

in your case it works like

```
class Parent<T> {

    var data:T

    init(data:T) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

class Child: Parent<String> {
    init(data: Double) {
        super.init(data: "\(data)")
    }
}

let c = Child(data: 4)
print(c.dynamicType) // Child    :-)
```

Comment: See the above reply to @Paulw11... do you know why a method (other then an initializer) does not need to be overridden? If the language treated initializers the same as other methods in this case, what would be the danger?

Comment: hm ... initializers are not as other methods. you don't need to override default empty init(){}. before initializing an instance, you are not able to use any of instance methods, or functions, properties ....

Comment: You're right - you don't need to override the default empty `init`. But that only confuses me more! :-)

Comment: from apple docs "Swift’s approach prevents a situation in which a simple initializer from a superclass is inherited by a more specialized subclass and is used to create a new instance of the subclass that is not fully or correctly initialized"

Comment: That quote from the Swift docs doesn't explain why this only applies to generic classes in this case. In my original example, if `Parent` were not a generic class, then in fact, `Child` inherits the initializer just fine.

Comment: give me an example, please. class Child : Parent<Int> {} has no sense for me at all ...

Comment: Okay - not sure if it will help at all, but I've added some more context to my original question.