# Initializers from generic types won't be inherited in swift?

Tags: swift, generics, initializer

Here is my code:

```
public class A<T : Any> { 
    public init(n : Int) { 
        print("A")
    } 
} 
public class B : A<Int> {
}
public class C : B {
}
let x = C(n: 123)
```

This fails compilation and yells such error:

```
repl.swift:9:9: error: 'C' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
```

The following code can be compiled.

```
public class A { 
    public init(n : Int) { 
        print("A")
    } 
} 
public class B : A {
}
public class C : B {
}
let x = C(n: 123)
```

**Shouldn't requirement types specified generic types' initializers be inherited?**

*========Additional Below=======*

> “Superclass initializers are inherited in certain circumstances, but only when it is safe and appropriate to do so. For more information, see Automatic Initializer Inheritance below.”
> ---Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2)” iBooks.

And this

> “However, superclass initializers are automatically inherited if certain conditions are met.”
>
> “Assuming that you provide default values for any new properties you introduce in a subclass, the following two rules apply:”
> **Rule 1**
> “If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.”
> **Rule 2**
> “If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.”

When looking into the first code, subclass `B` doesn't define any designated initializers,it should automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers, those from `A<Int>`.But actually it didn't which seems wired to me.

Comment: Also observed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040044/swift-generic-superclass-init-not-accesible-when-constructing-its-subclass.

Comment: someone has lodged a ticket in swift jira https://bugs.swift.org/projects/SR/issues/SR-416

Comment: @AnthonyKong Yes that's me.

Answer (score 1):

How about that ?? I try to use override code and super.init, it 's not error. I think that you don't have to init function with generic types.

try to put override init function in class B and class C.
Look like this,

`public override init(n:Int) {
        super.init(n: n)
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Your failing code now compiles (since Swift 3). There is no mention of this change in the [Swift 3 Language changes](https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-0-released/), so I can only assume that this was a bug.